# DateTime in linq

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime, linq-to-sql, ssis

So I was trying to just grab the most recent record from a table inside of a script task.  The error is coming in the Linq query it looks like:

`"Could not Translate expression 'Table(SSASLogging).Select(r=>r.TimeStamp).Max()' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression."`

The problem lies in the DateTime data type, but I need the DateTime to give it to my SSIS variable.  I know this could be done easily in an Execute SQL Task but Im too far along to give up now!  I know there are some LinqToSQL methods for DateTime but they are for comparison it looks like, Im not sure how to apply them here.

```
    public DateTime getLatest()
    {
        DateTime result = new DateTime();

        //temp dummy/defaul date is two days ago
        result = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);

        try
        {
            //get the data connection string from the connection manager
            RW = (string)Dts.Connections["ReportingWarehouse"].ConnectionString;

            //Remove the Provider, Auto Translate, and Application
            //as it is not a parameter for the DataContext constructor
            RW = RW.Remove(RW.IndexOf("Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;"), "Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;".Length);
            RW = RW.Remove(RW.IndexOf("Auto Translate=False;"), "Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;".Length);
            RW = RW.Remove(RW.IndexOf("Application"),RW.Length - RW.IndexOf("Application"));



            MessageBox.Show(RW);

            //get the last insertion date from the SSASLoging table
            using (DataContext RWData = new DataContext(RW))
            {
                Table<SSASLogging> records = RWData.GetTable<SSASLogging>();
                var rs = (from r in records
                         select r.TimeStamp).Max();
                //result = rs.FirstOrDefault();
            }

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception in Retrieving latesttime" + e.Message + "/n"
                            + e.StackTrace);
        }

        return result;
   }

}//end partial class


[Table]  
public class SSASLogging  
{
    [Column(Name = "CREATED_TIMESTAMP")] 
    private DateTime timeStamp;

    public DateTime TimeStamp 
    {
        get { return this.TimeStamp; }
    }
}//End SSASLogging
```

Comment: what is the type of `r.TimeStamp` in both, Database and Model?

Comment: the type in the database is DateTime and the type in the package is DateTime.  Im not sure what you mean by the model?

Comment: Are you able to select list of all dates from `r.TimeStamp`, without specifying `Max()`?

Comment: yes i can do that if I leave off Max it runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sorting the table and `Take(1).ToList()`. It should return `List` with 0 or 1 element. Then you can use `FirstOrDefault`, which will be performed by application, not by SQL:

```
var rs = (from r in records
          orderby r.TimeStamp descending
          select r).Take(1).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: same deal here.  'No supported Transaltion in SQL'

Answer (score 2):

If `Max` isn't working, what about this:

```
var maxDate =
    (from r in records
     orderby r.TimeStamp descending
     select r.TimeStamp)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: First or default was the first thing I tried and it gave me a 'has no supported translation to SQL' error

Comment: @Mike_L just curious, if you put the `[Column]` attribute on the property `TimeStamp` rather than the field `timeStamp`, does it run?

Answer (score 1):

You can try OrderBy

```
var rs = (from r in records  orderby r.TimeStamp descending
                     select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @Mike_L he was a bit quicker :) So it gives your exception on FirstOrDefault?

Comment: yeah I meant I tried that before I even posted here at all. Yeah it gives an exception for FirstOrDefault.  I tried some of the Convert.ToDateTime inside of the select too and DateTime.Date

Comment: @Mike_L Does this thing works? records.ToList().OrderByDescending(r=>r.TimeStamp).Select(r=>r.TimeStamp).FirstOrDefault(); Can you convert your records to List?

Comment: actually im getting a syntax error here it doesnt liek that FirstOrDefault where it is

Comment: @Mike_L I suppose you have to convert your result set to collection type. It is hard to write you a propper example without having your Model. But I advice you to split your Linq on select part, assign it to some var (it should have IQuerable<T> type), and then try to convert this var to list and make Max or OrderBy on this collection.

Comment: how do i give you my model?  You mean copy/paste the whole code?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff963710.aspx

so:

```
var rs = (from r in records.AsEnumerable()
         select r.TimeStamp).Max();
```

or:

```
var rs = (from r in records
         select r.TimeStamp).AsEnumerable().Max();
```

Comment: for some reason this makes ssis just completely puase and do nothing.  The script task just stays yellow.

Comment: but it doesnt work.  SSIS stops working, there is a dialog box that comes out and stops SSIS.